# XerServer 6.5: Can't start xapi after Power outage

Tags: xenserver

I'm currently testing XenServer 6.5 to be used on the production environment of my company. However, whenever I test its behaviour when facing an unexpected shutdown (i.e.: power outage), xapi service won't start anymore. Trying to bring it back manually produces the following output:

```
[root@xenserver-45 ~]# service xapi start
Starting xapi: OK [ OK ]
[root@xenserver-45 ~]# sudo service xapi status 
xapi dead but pid file exists
```

It already happened 3 times and all I was able to do to solve the problem was reinstall it from scratch. Every single time it happened, messages like those on http://pastebin.com/VkVxdMsU appears on /var/log/xensource.log when trying to start xapi.

Searching around, I've found some people saying that it could be a partition that runned out of space, but that's not the case. Other people said It could be /var/xapi/state.db that is corrupted, but I've already checked it too and its XML structure is just fine. I'm about to give up XenServer cause it doesn't seem to be that reliable. Any ideas of what can be done to bring xapi back?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Have you tried deleting the .pid file ?

Comment: Yes, but it hasn't worked, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

No explicit error spotted in `/var/log/xensource.log`. You may need to do a `tail -F /var/log/xensource.log` and restart toolstack `xe-toolstack-restart`, see the output for errors.

Most likely the `/var/xapi/state.db` is corrupted. You can try to rename it and start toolstatck, it will generate a new state.db (but settings will be lost). See if this at least helps to start xapi.

If no luck, you may have to consider reinstall using the install CD (it will keep stuff in local storage, just be careful).

HTH